# How to extrapolate cross tabulation analysis?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, statistics

First, for gene G, I want to create a pandas dataframe for `control` and `experimental` conditions, where the ratio of 0:1 is 10% and 20%, respectively.

```
import pandas as pd

n = 5000

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
     {"Cells": (f'Cell{x}' for x in range(1, n+1)), "Control": np.random.choice([1,0], p=[0.1, 0.9], size=n), "Experimental": np.random.choice([1,0], p=[0.1+0.1, 0.9-0.1], size=n)},
     orient='columns'
)

df = df.set_index("Cells")
```

Second, I perform cross-tabulation analysis for gene G.

```
# Contingency table/array
table = pd.crosstab(df.index, [df["Control"], df["Experimental"]])
table
```

Now, I want to extrapolate the conditions from step 1 and 2 for 1000 genes and then perform cross-tabulation. How?

Comment: what does this have to do with the [`xarray`](https://xarray.pydata.org/) package? If nothing, please remove the `python-xarray` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle it. One of the easiest would be:

1. Wrap the *simulation procedure* in a function and run it for each gene to create a list of genes based results.
2. *Concat* all the gene_based simulations and run the *crosstab* function to get the contingency tables in a single *dataframe*.

Something like:

```
n = 100   # no of records per simulation/ gene
nog = 2   # no of genes
gene_list = ["gene_" + str(i) for i in range(0,nog)]

# simulation procedure
def generate_gene_df(gene, n):

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
         {"Gene" : gene,
          "Cells": (f'Cell{x}' for x in range(1, n+1)),
          "Control": np.random.choice([1,0], p=[0.1, 0.9], size=n),
          "Experimental": np.random.choice([1,0], p=[0.1+0.1, 0.9-0.1], size=n)},
         orient='columns'
    )

    df = df.set_index(["Gene","Cells"])
    
    return df

# create a list of gene based simulations generated using your procedure
gene_df_list = [generate_gene_df(gene, n) for gene in gene_list]

single_genes_df = pd.concat(gene_df_list)
single_genes_df = single_genes_df.reset_index()


table = pd.crosstab([single_genes_df["Gene"], single_genes_df["Cells"]], 
                    [single_genes_df["Control"], single_genes_df["Experimental"]])
table
```

[image]

Comment: I  only have one gene. But I want to extrapolate it to 1000 genes. Does it mean n=1...or is it n=1000?

Comment: Depends on your requirement of the simulation, n and nog can be anything you want.

Comment: For each of the 1000 gene, I'm assuming that they all have the same ratio but randomly scattered across the rows.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So should I change `nog` to 1000? I know you gave a random value but I'm wondering what I should use.

Comment: Yeah. Go ahead. change nog = 1000 (i.e. number of genes under analysis). and n to however big you want (i.e based on number of simulated records you want)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Here is the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252052/how-to-perform-mcnemar-or-chi-square-test-on-multi-dimensional-data